# Sequences in Hausdorff spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence, continuity

As far as I see is the sequence concept in Hausdorff spaces well-defined in the sense that we have unique limits. Thus, I was wondering whether the definition of the closure of a set that contains all possible limit points of sequences and the definition of a continuous function as $$x_n \rightarrow x \Rightarrow f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$$ still hold here or whether they are somehow weaker/stronger concepts in this context?

Comment: They are weaker. Those are "sequential closedness" and "sequential continuity". In first countable spaces (and some others), they coincide with closedness and continuity, but in general, they are strictly weaker. You need nets or filters to characterise closedness and continuity by limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the notion of nets for this. For instance, we have that a sequence in $\ell_1(\mathbb{N})$ converges to $x$ in the weak topology if and only if it converges in the $||\cdot||_1$ topology to $x$ (not entirely trivial). Both are Hausdorff, but have different topologies.

EDIT: Very sorry. Big mistake corrected I hope.